# Copy nested tabulator data to clipboard

Tags: tabulator

I am trying to copy nested tabulator data to clipboard functionality that Tabulator provides. I am stuck as when i hit 'ctrl+c' and paste it to excel file, it doesn't give me the nested tabulator. 
My Table is something like this : [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OWcz.png)

I even tried

```
rowGroups : true
```

but it still doesn't give me what is displayed in the screenshot.
Can you help me out in this ?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you cannot nested tables to the clipboard, the ***rowGroups*** option refers to the [Row Groups](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.1/group) option for grouping whole sets of rows.